# Multicore / Parallel simulation in R using doRedis and doMC on AWS EC2

Tags: r, parallel-processing, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, redis

I have a simulation function that is very applicable to parallel processing. I have managed to make it run multicore (up to 32 cores on EC2 cc2.8xlarge).

Now i am wondering if I can also use Redis to make it run in multiple instances multiple cores in parallel.

The core of my simulation function is essentially

```
library(doMC)
registerDoMC(cores=32)
simresults<-foreach (i=1:nrow(input.data), .combine=c) %dopar% {
    simulation function (input.data$1[i],input.data$2[i],input.data$3[i])
}
```

simresults is then a vector of the results i gather. The simulation runs a couple of 10^7 times.

Is this possible with `doRedis` or any other tool (`segue`?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is and there are several examples floating around -- see for example the [rredis Manual vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rredis/vignettes/rredis.pdf) of the [rredis](http://cran.r-project.org/package=rredis) package.

There are of course other options besides redis and multicore.